# iOS - Icon Stretching on Startup

Tags: ios, iphone, icons

So when you want to get to an app, you have to click on the app's icon. When I do that, the icon itself stretches out to fill up the entire screen. Every icon suggestion I've read has opined that I make the icons 120X120 or some other version of a square image. I've done that, but so long as it's a square image if the app tries to make it fit into a rectangle it is going to stretch.

On top of that icon is the splash image with *is* rectangular and looks just fine, but I don't know how to tell it to not use the square icon behind it. Thoughts?

Comment: do you have a screenshot? whats your launch image?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this for the 6+/7+ only, you need to have launch images for both portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 0):

On opening the app, are you simply wanting to use the image used for your app icon to appear full screen for the splash/loading screen while it is being launched?

If this ***is*** the case, the app icon itself is not the image that will stretch, rather, you need to make a separate launch image of how you expect full screen size image to look. The app icon will display according the the image you have saved as the icon (correct HIG sizes/filenames) and then when it's loading, the app will automatically switch to display your launch image.

Please read this Apple information on [Human Interface Guidelines (HIG)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html) as it tells you what images will be needed and what to do.

I hope this helps answer you question.

Cheers, Jim.

Comment: Jim, the 1136x620 image (or whatever the resolution is) should be the only image on the splash screen from my view. Instead, I get that (well displayed image) on top of the stretched image that stretches from the icon itself across the page through an otherwise cool animation.

Comment: Hi, can you take a screenshot of what's happening that you need help with regarding the view? This could help clarify what the issue is. Cheers.